# git: files deleted on checkout

Tags: git

I've two branches  `master` and `development` both have an `.env` file (configuration file) which is added in `.gitignore` in both branches

but the problem when checkout from `production` branch to `master` branch `.env` file is deleted in `master` branch

Again checkout into `production` branch `.env` exists but its deleted from `master` branch

But i want keep `.env` file in both branches

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: And what does `php` do here?

Comment: Naming a file in `.gitignore` does not affect its existence in any existing commit. If the file *is* in commit A and *is not* in commit B, and you first check out commit A, then check out commit B, the file will be added to (A), and then removed from (B), your index/staging-area and work-tree.

Comment: So what's the solution of my problem